# Material-UI Datagrid Cutting Off Last Row

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

I am running into an issue where a Material-UI Datagrid with a fixed number of rows is cutting off part of the last row (see pic below).  The height of the Datagrid is *autoHeight*.

[Image of Datagrid with last row cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjUJR.png)

This is the code for the component (note the *{...rest}* of the properties are the column definitions, the data source, the filter model, etc.; there are no styles in these properties):

```
<DataGrid
   disableColumnSelector
   autoHeight
   paginationModel={paginationModel}
   onPaginationModelChange={handlePageChange}      
   isRowSelectable={() => false}
   pagination
   {...rest}
   classes={{
     root: classes.root,
     columnHeader: classes.columnHeader,
     cell: classes.cell,
     row: classes.row,
   }}
/>
```

And these are the CSS styles used:

```
{
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      height: props?.height ?? "unset",
      "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer": {
        padding: `0px 0px 0px 0px`,
      },
    },
    columnHeader: {
      '&[role="columnheader"]:focus': {
        outline: "none",
        boxShadow: "none",
      },
    },
    cell: {
      outline: "none",
      '&[data-editable="false"]:focus': {
        outline: "none",
      },
      "&.MuiDataGrid-cell--editing": {
        boxShadow: "none",
        outline: "none",
      },
    },
    row: {
      borderTop: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
      borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
      "&.MuiDataGrid-row:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      },
    },
  }
```